# jQuery .slideDown(); crashing Android Browser

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I've got a problem that has me stumped.  I'm building a fairly simple mobile site and want to use jQuery to make a menu for all the pages.  I have a simple UList that is holding the menu elements.  It's hidden via CSS when I load the page

```
item { display:none }
```

I want to use the following to display it when a "link" is clicked:

```
    $("header div.menu-box a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if($("#header_wrapper .menu-box .menu-text").text() == 'Menu') {
        $("#header_wrapper .menu-box .menu-text").text("Close");
        $("#popmenu").slideDown(500);
    }
    else {
        $("#header_wrapper .menu-box .menu-text").html("Menu");
        $("#popmenu").slideUp(500);
    }
    return false;
});
```

It works fine in Firefox & Safari with an iPhone browser agent, as well as on an iPhone.  However on my new Android Razr it crashes the browser.  Any ideas would be VERY welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS transitions? http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Comment: Looking into the transitions thing now but want it to be simple to maintain across all browsers.

Comment: Does it crash when the duration is 0 instead of 500?

Comment: Interesting... it doesn't crash with a 0 but it does with any other number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery effects (slideUp, etc) will crash Android browsers because of this [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12497) which has been fixed in jQuery 1.8.3 (1.8.2 still crashes Android).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though this is an issue with Android's browser, not your code. In theory, on a secure browser, no unprivileged JavaScript code should be able to cause the entire browser to "crash".

Answer (score 0):

maybe `console.log()` doesn't exist?

Comment: I removed it and it still is giving me the crash.