# Android stock browser on Xperia Z does not render html correctly

Tags: android, jquery, android-browser

I have an HTML page which is displayed correctly in all devices and all browser except the stock Android browser in Xperia Z.

On this particular device running Android 4.2.2, I am using jQuery v1.7.2, and using `$('div').slideUp` and `$('div').slideDown` methods only, and it results in text distortion (it is in English, so I suppose it is not related to any specific font), the text appears as horizontal lines as they would appear for a fraction of a second while sliding up/ down.

I have tried turning the debug mode ON by `about:debug` in the stock browser, and the javascript console shows no error/ warning messages.

I tried changing the user agent string to iPhone, and to my surprise, the text is rendered as expected.

I have searched for similar issue, and came across [Android stock browser crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733720/jquery-slidedown-crashing-android-browser), it points to jQuery bug where slideUp/ slideDown have problems in Android stock browser (please note that jQuery and Android versions are different in the reported bug).

My questions are:

1. Is this a known issue?
2. Has anyone faced similar problem before?
3. Is there a workaround to resolve it?

I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I have an Xperia M with me. It came with Google's chrome browser installed - the old stock broswer isn't anywhere to be seen. Is this the same browser, or are you talking about the old android browser (I _think_ it comes in the emulator)

Comment: Just to be clear, your not talking about Android's WebView, correct?

Comment: @chronodekar: I think from Android KitKat they've replaced stock browser with Chrome, I have this issue with the 'old Android browser'

Randy: I couldn't see anything related to WebView, please advise if I need to have a look at WebView.